# Unity OnTriggerEnter Multiple Call Problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

I only have Rigidbody in my character. **No collider component.**

There is only BoxCollider in the object it touches and the IsTrigger bool is true.

Although I have tried all kinds of code in the code.But not fixed. Call the multiple times error and print Log.

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Respawn"))
          RandomChange();
}


private void RandomChange()
{
   // TO DO
   Debug.Log("CHARACTER ENTERED")
}
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Can you rephrase it properly?

Comment: Can you post more information? Not posting any code nor setup leaves us completely in the dark as to what the issue could be. What kind of collider is on your player component? Are you sure you are not using `OnTriggerStay` instead of `OnTriggerEnter`?

Comment: I've added some more code to help you understand this question.
That's all the question, and that's all I can tell.

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve .. and what is happening instead?

Comment: Once it should work. one time >> ( RandomChange() )
 But Two or more worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Rigidbody to work, you **need** a collider component. Without one, the game doesn’t know what or where you want the player to be.

Unity is very customizable, and it lets you choose what counts as part of the player. For example, you might not want a cape to count as a collider. The cape should not have a collider because it would affect the physics. Something might knock the player over by hitting the cape (like it is part of the actual person).

Unity has its own mesh collider, which you can attach for all of the vertices to count as a collider.

---

**The Fix**

To fix this, adding a capsule collider to the player should work (any other collider will work, capsules are good for players, though).